# Get the field data in email body

Tags: emails

whenever user creates content, I want to get the few fields data of content in the mail body and trigger mail,, as of now i have created rule to trigger mail with text comparison condition for specific field.

ex: I have content with user id, pancard Id fields etc,now i want to get this content field data in mail body and send mail to user.

Comment: Have you install token or entity token module? If it is eable you can add token of that field on message of that rules.

Comment: @VimalGoradiya: yes i have enabled

Comment: then use the tokens in ur mail body field...

Comment: @ No Sssweat: do we need to add  fields tokens in the body, along with text????

Comment: @kashish It should be something like [comment:comment-body]  along with your text thats it.

Comment: @VimalGoradiya: ok thanks a lot.....i will try and update you soon):

Comment: @all, actually the same thing i followed 1]created component then in the body of the message i mentioned the tokens but the value of field data m unable to see the field data in the body of email....why is this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the kind of rule event which I expect to be "When a new content is created" in your case.

When you choose action of rule as "send email" it allows you to use tokens, as declared by [token modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/token). You will see the node tokens for the field as well, use it and those will get automatically replaced.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the hook_node_insert.

```
function yourmodule_node_insert(&$node) {
  $body = $node->body;
  drupal_mail('yourmodule', 'your_key', $to, user_preferred_language($user), array('body' => $body), $from, TRUE);
}
```

This hook will trigger whenever you create a node.

and then use hook_mail

```
function yourmodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'your_key':
      $message['body'][] = t('@body', array('@body' => $params['body']));
      $message['subject'] = $subject;
      break;

  }
}
```