# adding the field tokens while creating the component

Tags: emails

I created the component, in body of the message i added the token based on machine name but i am unable to fetch the data of the fields of content i,e when email triggers to user in the body of the email field data is not showing based on the content created, i have followed this method [Get the field data in email body](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/174531/get-the-field-data-in-email-body?noredirect=1#comment210119_174531). please give suggestion why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29225/discussion-on-question-by-kashish-adding-the-field-tokens-while-creating-the-com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rules you need to use `-` not a `_`

Try

```
[node:field-working]
[node:field-remoz]
```

**EDIT**

[image]

Click on replacement patterns, it will show you all the fields that you can use. Look for your field on the list, and then use the code that is given there, and copy and paste it into the message body.